# Array of objects, find by index as string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my array of objects:

```
export const reminderButtonLabels = [
  {
    MOT: {
      label: 'Book garage',
      url: 'xxx',
    },
  },
  { Tax: { label: 'Tax vehicle', url: 'xxx' } },
  {
    Service: {
      label: 'Book garage',
      url: 'xxx',
    },
  },
  {
    Insurance: {
      label: 'Get quote',
      url: 'xxx',
    },
  },
];
```

In my component I am trying to lookup the array object data by reminderType: `MOT, Tax, Service, Insurance`. However, I get undefined, how can I get my array data by `reminderType`?

```
const ReminderRow: FunctionComponent<{
  reminder: reminder;
}> = ({ reminder }) => {
  console.log('reminder data', reminderButtonLabels.indexOf[reminder.reminderType]);
```

Comment: What about using [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)? `reminderButtonLabels.findIndex(obj => obj[key])`

Comment: `indexOf` would only work if the thing you were looking for was directly _in_ the array. There's no way for it to know you mean _"if the thing I'm looking for is the (only?) key in the object in the array"_.

Comment: This code doesn't make a lot of sense. You're trying to access a function (`indexOf()`) with square bracket access notation (`indexOf[]`)? But actually, you're not even looking for the index but for the data. And why not just use a single object instead of an array of single property objects? Then you could just do `reminderButtonLabels[reminder.reminderType]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise to change your array to something like this instead:

```
export const reminderButtonLabels = [
  {
    label: 'Book garage',
    url: 'xxx',
    type: 'MOT',
  },
  {
    label: 'Tax vehicle',
    url: 'xxx',
    type: 'Tax',
  },
  {
    label: 'Book garage',
    url: 'xxx',
    type: 'Service',
  },
  {
    label: 'Get quote',
    url: 'xxx',
    type: 'Insurance',
  },
];
```

And then find the object you want by doing:

`reminderButtonLabels.find((label) => label.type === reminder.reminderType)`